# What are coins used for in Orcs Must Die 2?

Tags: orcs-must-die-2

In Orcs must die 2 there is a weapon that 'increases the amount of gold dropped when killed on it'. I checked the menu and all of the stuff you can buy is using skulls. What are coins used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coins are used to deploy traps.